# Saving DEAP results into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, genetic-algorithm, deap

Using DEAP package for genetic algorithm for a while.

I have known the routine and get some valid results.

But I want to know the variation of the fitness function among populations.

With **stats** function, I can print the mean, std etc as the output.

The manual has told that **logbook** is used for saving the results. I haven't learned that and I don't familiar with the **pickle**.

Is there any way to save the result in .csv or excel format directly?

Answer (score 1):

The logbook is a list of dictionaries, so you need to "transpose" that data into a dictionary of lists.

This is how I did it for a Logbook with multistatistics using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce
from operator import add, itemgetter

chapter_keys = logbook.chapters.keys()
sub_chaper_keys = [c[0].keys() for c in logbook.chapters.values()]

data = [list(map(itemgetter(*skey), chapter)) for skey, chapter 
             in zip(sub_chaper_keys, logbook.chapters.values())]
data = np.array([[*a, *b] for a, b in zip(*data)])

columns = reduce(add, [["_".join([x, y]) for y in s] 
                       for x, s in zip(chapter_keys, sub_chaper_keys)])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

keys = logbook[0].keys()
data = [[d[k] for d in logbook] for k in keys]
for d, k in zip(data, keys):
    df[k] = d
```

First, I parse the statistics to an array and create a dataframe. Second, I add the columns which are not based on a statistic (i.e. gen or evals) as a column to my df. You can export the dataframe to csv using `df.to_csv`.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a single statistic (no chapters) to Pandas dataframe use this

```
data = [[i for i in item.values()] for item in log]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=log.header)
print(df)
```

because the data is in the logbook object itself.